Google map directions delay loading the itinerary
I'm using google map intent in my react native application has been almost one year without any problem passing the coordinates in this url allowing the user to open "Google maps" on navigating mode to the exact destination :
const destination = `${coordinates.latitude},${coordinates.longitude}`;
const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&dir_action=navigate&destination=${destination}`;

Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
    return null
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));

But since last week "12/06/2024", the map opens in the navigation mode but it takes long time to load the itinerary.
here you can find a video of the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U7l7tK9EzKGd9_nxDZtfpUQEQMwWtko-/view?usp=sharing
Can you please tell me if you are facing the same problem, or is there any solution.
I tried to open the link outside my app :
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&dir_action=navigate&destination=${destination}
but gives the same result.
I do except to load the itinerary instantly.

I tried using the google maps for web and on my android phone. And the itinerary (route) from point a to b displayed immediately for me.
